# How to query multiple nested fields in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery

When i query two level nested field i miss some rows.

The schema is like this:

```
Productid   STRING  REQUIRED 
Variants    RECORD  REPEATED
Variants.SKU    STRING  NULLABLE
Variants.Size   STRING  NULLABLE
Variants.Prices RECORD  REPEATED
Variants.Prices.Country STRING  NULLABLE
Variants.Prices.Currency    STRING  NULLABLE
```

Some of Variants.Prices records are empty.

When i query this table with this query:

```
select Productid,Variants.SKU,Variants.Size
from ga-export-0000.feed.feed_dev
,UNNEST (Variants) AS Variants
```

i get many more rows than with this one:

```
select Productid,Variants.SKU,Variants.Size
,Prices.Currency,Prices.Country
from ga-export-0000.feed.feed_dev
,UNNEST (Variants) AS Variants
,UNNEST(Variants.Prices) as Prices
```

That's because it doesn't returns rows with missing Variants.Prices.

How can i modify my second query so it returns all the rows and if Variants.Prices is missing it shows NULL?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Comment: Thanks @Pentium10, just went through all my questions and marked accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Flattening arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening-arrays) topic in the documentation. Instead of a comma, use `LEFT JOIN`, e.g.:

```
select Productid,Variants.SKU,Variants.Size
,Prices.Currency,Prices.Country
from `ga-export-0000.feed.feed_dev`
,UNNEST (Variants) AS Variants
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(Variants.Prices) as Prices
```

This will return a `NULL` value of `Prices` if that array is empty.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott, that worked! 
How can i use where clause now? When i do `where Prices.Country in ('GB',NULL)` i get only rows that have Prices.Country=GB and don't have those empty ones.

Comment: `IN` returns `NULL` if an element is `NULL`, so you can't use that for the comparison. Instead, use `Prices.Country IS NULL OR Prices.Country = 'GB'`.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott! When i try `where Prices.Country = 'GB'` condition i still get results like this: [link](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2345250/4446c2daf89ec5fb7c44cf79ad088fdc) . What is wrong with my condition and how shall i use it?

Comment: Based on that output it looks like you are selecting the original `Prices` as part of the `SELECT` list rather than the one resulting from `UNNEST`. It might be a good idea to call the one from `UNNEST` as `Price` (singular) for instance.